# I can't figure out how to make this code work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a new js programmer. I can't figure out how to make this code work!

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

let buttonIsClicked = false;

button.onclick = () =>{
    buttonIsClicked = true;
}

if ( buttonIsClicked == true ) {
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
} else {
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

I tried googleing it, but I cant figure it out.

Comment: At the least, move the `if/else` statement inside the `onclick` closure

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the background color of button outside the click. it only runs once, when the script is initially loaded.

You should write,

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

let buttonIsClicked = false;

button.onclick = () =>{
    buttonIsClicked = true;

    if (buttonIsClicked == true) {
        body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    } else {
        body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
}
```